# How to convert array([array([ ....],type=float32)],[array([ ....],type=float32)]) to array([...],[...])?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

Here is my code:

```
def extract_doc2vec(doc, w2v):
vecs = [w2v[word] for word in doc if word in w2v]
if len(vecs) > 0:
    vecs = np.asarray(vecs).sum(axis=0)
    return vecs
y = newsgroups_all['target']

x= []

for doc in newsgroups_all['data']:
    edv = extract_doc2vec(list(gensim.utils.tokenize(doc)),model.wv)
    x.append(edv)
```

I have to convert retrain_doc which can be fit into

```
for train_index, test_index in sssd.split(x, y):
   X_train, X_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: The last argument in your title question is an array of lists. I assume you actually want a two-dimensional array instead?

Comment: @00 ya and  i have to split x with StratifiedShuffleSplit

Comment: I haven't tried, but does `np.vstack(myarray)` work for you?

Comment: I have rolled back the original code, since it is unclear whether the indentation fix introduced by jdehesa is correct. Perhaps it's just part that misses an indent, and that edit could have masked the end of a block. However, please do fix your question by [edit]ing it and applying the appropriate indentation.

Comment: I suspect the subarrays differ in shape. If they are all the same then `np.stack` can join them.  But if different, they can't be rows of a 2d array.

Comment: working fine after removing arrays which are differ in shape

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list x into data frame then convert it into numpy array and apply shuffle split

```
data = pd.DataFrame(x).to_numpy()
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what shuffle split is and why you need to convert to both pandas and numpy for this.